# How to run a new app that didn't get added to the launcher

Tags: launcher

I installed a new app (VMware Player, using the answer from another question) and it didn't get added to the launcher. That is when I realized that without the launcher, I'm dead-in-the-water. I don't know where to find the app. I did find help on how to add something to the launcher, but they assumed that one would already know where to find the executable.

So, where do the executables reside, and what identifies them as such?

Thanks.

Comment: It just may not have a .desktop file.  Run it from the alt-f2 run a command blob interface.

Answer (score 0):

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and after write the name of the application that you want to search (VMware Player in your case). After this your application will suddenly should appear.